# How to load and open video player when we click on m3u8 File android

Tags: android, m3u8

I have a file of m3u8,I want to start the live stream when i click on the file i was able to show the app name but i don't know how to parse the url from m3u8 file and start streaming.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

open m3u8 file in Notepad++ copy the m3u8 link and paste in m3u8 player to run m3u8 stream. Or you can directly open m3u8 player by clicking on m3u8 link.